# Proposition: the value of the wedge product of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a real number. What about the cross product?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, mathematical-physics, exterior-algebra, cross-product

An example of where this question presents itself is in the canonical isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.  For $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}\in\mathbb{C}$ I have been writing

$$\mathfrak{a}^{*}\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\mathfrak{b}+i\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}.$$

A similar circumstance arises when working with central force problems, such as Kepler orbits.  Often all that is needed from a cross product is the *signed* magnitude of the projection of a vector onto the normal of another.  That is, for example

$$v\sin\left[\varphi\right]=\left(\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\times\mathfrak{v}\right)\cdot\hat{\mathfrak{\omega}},$$

gives the scalar component of $\mathfrak{v}$ lying in the orbital plane, and normal to $\hat{\mathfrak{r}}.$  Which is a genuinely cumbersome expression.

I know there are other ways of writing both expressions which do not involve a wedge or cross product.  But, the wedge and cross products seem most natural.  In the latter, there really is a third dimension which provides an axis for the signed magnitude of the cross product.  Nonetheless, once an argument has been made that the problem is essentially two dimensional, that third dimension serves as nothing more than a "bookkeeping" mechanism.  It's just a place to put a scalar value.

In the case of the wedge product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the same sort of thing is happening.  We have the bivector $\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}$ which has only one component.  I argue that in both of these cases a mathematically satisfactory argument can be made for writing the desired result as a wedge product, and treating it as a real number.

Another way of saying this is that all $\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}\backepsilon\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ live in a one-dimensional vector space which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

So I propose that writing

$$\mathfrak{a}\cdot\mathfrak{b}+i\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}=ab\left(\cos \varphi+\mathrm{i}\sin\varphi\right),$$

is not merely a convenient mathematical "slang." It is, ineed a completely legitimate mathematical statement.

The argument in support of treating the cross product as a real number is a bit more complicated, since in the case of Kepler orbits, the 3 dimensional interpretation of the cross product has its uses.  In the case of $\mathbb{C}\leftrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ the cross and wedge products are synonymous.  That is, if we even allow for a cross product.

So I ask: **is there a valid mathematical argument against treating**

$$\mathfrak{a}^{*}\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\mathfrak{b}+i\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}$$

**as a complex number expression**?

What about

$$v\sin\left[\varphi\right]=\hat{\mathfrak{r}}\wedge\mathfrak{v}?$$

Comment: I would think that a "natural" way to form a wedge product of two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is to think of them as vectors of $\Bbb{R}^3$, and then calculate the usual cross product. This is necessarily parallel to the $z$-axis, so we can ignore its direction (except that we do observe its sign) and think of it as a scalar. This will calculate the (oriented) area of the parallelogram with the two vectors as sides, as expected/required. Don't know if there is a natural way to think of it in terms of complex numbers? Anticommutativity makes it a bit tricky.

Comment: (con'td) I guess the imaginary part $\operatorname{Im} z_1\overline{z_2}$ can be used, but I didn't check that it fits everything you want to use it for.

Comment: As I stated, there are other ways of writing these things.  The expression $\mathfrak{a}^{*}\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{a}\cdot\mathfrak{b}+i\mathfrak{a}\wedge\mathfrak{b}$ seems more expressive than the alternatives.  See the "complex structure" on page 4 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1POPT0isCJQAUKoHq3fnZ-pkFvxZIXvMs/view?usp=sharing of my notes.

Comment: As for treating the wedge product as a cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3,$  it seems that one of the reasons for using the wedge product is to keep our geometry intrinsic.  The cross product in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ does not transform in the same way as a radial vector.  It is really (according to Weyl, et al.,) an anti-symmetric rank-2 tensor.  But, then, so is the wedge product.  My argument is that under the restrictions stated, it can be treated exactly as a real number.  And it seems to have the right connotation, as well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar

Comment: Abuse of notation stops being abuse of notation if you properly define the symbols you have written. In this case you need to properly define the isomorphism $\Lambda^2 (\Bbb R^2)\to \Bbb R$, then there is no problem.

Comment: @amd Thanks for the informative reference.  One method of extending the domain of natural numbers to the domain of integers is a "parity inversion" in the formal equation of natural number addition.  I guess my proposition may reduce to a question of what my reader will accept.  Perhaps I could introduce a "polymorphism" for tensor expressions appearing in scalar expressions saying they should automatically convert to scalars where applicable.